# Is risk to show session id to publicly?

Tags: php

I want to know if someone knows my session id from HTML source, then they can hack my site?

For example, if i set a class in html like this `<div class="class<?php echo session_id(); ?>"></div>`

Then the HTML source code (that can be viewed from the browser) wil be `<div class="class78345543545c344x"></div>`

Is it risk?

Comment: If someone gets access to your PHPSESSID, one can mimic your sessions and steal data.

Comment: free session fixation

Comment: I don't understand bro. can you give me a link?

Comment: i don't see why you would want ot use such a class- that's more the issue here

Comment: Suppose you had an XSS vulnerability in your site, or a 3rd party manages to insert JavaScript into it some other way (f.e. by hacking the service that serves ads on your site.) Now if the session id was stored in a cookie, that cookie could be set with the `httpOnly` attribute, which means there would be no client-side access to it via JS – whereas JS running within the context of your page could easily read that class name you want to set, and send the the value to an external server. (And what would be the purpose of putting the session id into the class of an HTML element anyway?)

Comment: When you create the session, you could store the user's IP in a session variable, and on each page you could check whether their IP matches the original IP.

Comment: Thanks i understand but i want some unique id like session id which generate until browser close or more. I already tried such as md5 or php unique id but it every time changed when i reload browser.

Comment: The session id _is_ unique and random. People who know a lot more about this stuff than you do have implemented this. Trying to replace it with your own mechanism is just a really bad idea (especially on that level of knowledge.) Don’t put your session id into the HTML code for no good reason is the only possible answer to your question.

Comment: @Megi  That's what cookies are for. And you should consider sessionStorage as an alternative also (if you can use javascript of course)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No matter what you store in a user's session, do not, i repeat, do not share the session id to someone other that the current user. Even though the session id is stored in a cookie (if enabled) or passed by query parameter in each request, no other person than the current user should be aware of somebody else's session id. Otherwise, identity phishing is wide open.

As per one of your comments, you need a unique and random number until the session is finished, you could store it in session:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['myUniqueId'])) {
     $_SESSION['myUniqueId'] = rand(0, 99999999);
}
```

Comment: Any alternative of session id?

Comment: there are no alternatives in php, php needs a session id for each session created. You can use your own algorithm though or even use a hardcoded session id (which i strongly don't recommend).

Comment: Thanks bro.I want to know is it hackable?

Comment: pretty much everything is hackable nowadays, can you expand?

Comment: yes, it has nothing to do with the session id, it's just a random number stored in the session array.

Comment: No problem. glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes and No**. Really it depends on what data is stored in session.

The risk is that a session id is the token that php uses to associate session data with an individual request. If you store sensitive information in `$_SESSION` then it could open you up to hacks. If all you store are things like user's name, etc then *maybe*.

Remember that being able to access someone else's session id allows someone to **assume that person's identity** as far as your website is concerned.

Comment: _“If you store sensitive information in $_SESSION then it could open you up to hacks”_ – that’s a nonsense statement, “sensitive information” are stored in sessions all the time. What part of that information the server is willing to _output_ to anyone that knows the session id, is a completely different matter.

Comment: I am using opencart. so i don't konw what stored in session but any alternative of session id, i mean which allready stored/generate by php like session id?

Comment: @CBroe Session can be used to store temporary information that isn't authentication related. Just because it is uncommon does not make it nonsense.

Comment: @Megi if you are using any sort of login system then yes it is a security risk. Why don't you tell us the problem you are trying to solve by adding a unique ID to an HTML class and then someone can help with a proper answer.

Comment: Saying _“If you store sensitive information in $_SESSION then it could open you up to hacks”_ _is_ nonsense in its generality. It’s the same as saying, _“carrying money in your wallet could make you victim of a robbery.”_ (Now, taking your $100 bills and waving them around in public would be stupid of course – but storing information into the session is not doing that.)

Comment: I want some unique id like session id which generate until browser close or more. I already tried such as md5 or php unique id but it every time changed when i reload browser.

Comment: @CBroe you are assuming a login system because that is what your experience makes you think of first. What if all I use $_SESSION for is to increment a counter that isn't stored anywhere but tracks how many pages you viewed on a website, is that sensitive? My answer explains that a session id allows you to assume the person's identity. The rest is up to the individual application and how / what it does with $_SESSION.

Comment: _“My answer explains that a session id allows you to assume the person's identity”_ – so you’re assuming a login system as well in that scenario. _“What if all I use $_SESSION for is to increment a counter that isn't stored anywhere but tracks how many pages you viewed on a website, is that sensitive?”_ – no, of course not. But what sense does that made-up scenario make in the context of a question that reads, _“[can they] hack my site?”_ …?

Comment: *you’re assuming a login system as well* no, I am assuming `$_SESSION['counter']++;`. No log in, all anonymous, removed when your session expires. My answer explains what a session id is and what it is used for. The exact **can I be hacked or not depends on your usage of session data**. It is a generalized answer to a generalized question. This conversation has gone too off topic to continue. If you don't like my answer, down vote it.

Comment: _“no, I am assuming $_SESSION['counter']++;”_ – then explain how that is connected to _“allows you to assume the person's identity”_. I don’t know about you, but a simple counter does not have anything to do with my identity. “I. Am. Not. A. Number.”